# dailyLimitExceeded errors, but API Console shows 21% of quota

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

Using the Ruby API client, a service account, and at the "courtesy limit" of 50k requests/day, we start seeing this error after making just a few hundred requests.

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
        "message": "Quota Error: profileId ga:REDACTED has exceeded the daily request limit."
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Quota Error: profileId ga:REDACTED has exceeded the daily request limit."
  }
}
```

The API console shows that we are only at 21% of quota. The other day, the error started happening when we were around 51% of quota.

[image: screenshot of Google API Console showing 21% of quota]

Our usage has never been very aggressive:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the account-wide limit of 50,000 requests/day, [there is a smaller limit of 10,000 requests *per profile*/day](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas#core_reporting) you're probably hitting:

> **Core Reporting API and Real Time Reporting API**
>
> These quotas are specific to the Core Reporting API and Real Time
>   Reporting API:
>
> - 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day
> - 10 concurrent requests per view (profile)

Comment: So is Google trying to get me to artificially spread this across 5 profiles? I had already submitted a request for a 500,000 Analytics API daily quota. Do I also need to request an increase to the Core Reporting API daily quota, or will that automatically go up with respect to other quota increases?

Comment: @jelder I don't see anything to suggest that there is any way to lift the per-profile limit. You should contact Google Analytics support about that.

Comment: The 10k limit per view(profile) can't be increased.